# How to create multiple Dialogues?

Tags: mfc

In a Project I am using multiple dialogues so in that my requirement is while I am initiating dialog if it is modal then it should come top else it should be behind the parent window...so suggest me how to do it???

Comment: Set the Z order on the dialog in OnInitDialog? And please show some research or at least an attempt at it.

Comment: Tell us what you want to achive exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Modal dialog always come to the top of the parent window. But what is the else case? You have a non-Modal dialog that should stay behind the Parent window? This doesn't make sense to me.

But if you want to have a non-modal dialog behind the parent window (or any other window) you need to define NULL for the dialog as a parent (owner window). Than you can change the Z-order of the top level window to be behind/after the parent window (use SetWindowPos for this).

Please note that the user can always change the Z-Order of top-level windows when he clicks on it.

Remember: If the window is owned by a parent it is always on top of the owned window.

Comment: You are confusing child/parent and owned/owner relationships. A window is never *owned* by a *parent*. An *owned* window is owned by an *owner*. Your final statement is backwards as well: An owned window is always in front of its owner.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Maybe my english isn't as well as it should.